# Should I pad image array with zero after down scaling image for training dataset

Tags: python, image, opencv, machine-learning, face-recognition

I am preparing my dataset for training my Facenet based face recognition model. I'm using image augmentation for generating new images from one image.

I'm scaling down the image to generate one. Should I pad the image to resize it to original size with zeros(black) to retain the scaled-down image as well as have an image of the original size?

Will it be beneficial or bad for my model?

Original Size of Image: 250 x 250

Scale : 0.3

This is my current implementation for scaling and padding :

```py
black = np.zeros((175,75,3),dtype=np.uint8)
black_2 = np.zeros((250,175,3),dtype=np.uint8)
scale = resize(in_img,[250*0.3,250*0.3])
result = np.append(np.append(scale,black,axis=0),black_2,axis=1)
```

Comment: Why are you downscaling your image at the first place? It's a memory issue?

Comment: I'm using many other techniques too such as resize, crop, gaussian filter etc and down scaling is one of them. I'm doing this to increase the size of my training dataset.

Comment: In your model how are you going to use the augmented images? Are they going to be resized to a fixed size (either keeping aspect ratio or not), do you use patches and train on the original size, other choice?

Comment: I'm going to basically augment the original image to form new images. All the other augmentation techniques maintain the original size. I train my model on the original and the augmented images for the same label. My question is should I do the same i.e resize to original by padding black (zeros) when I downscale the image.

Comment: If your model requires the same size, downscaling and padding is used to train for smaller objects. If your model can be trained on any object, i.e via fixed size patches then adding pad wont have any major difference.

Comment: Actually, I'm not clear with the idea of patches. Could you please explain to me a bit more about what exactly are fixed size patches, in the case where I'm training a face recognition model?

Comment: Patches means that even if your image is of varying shapes, actually a fixed-shape image (named patch) is randomly chosen from your input to be used as training.

Comment: Will this method be efficient for training a facial recognition model cause if the patch is chosen randomly important parts/features of some images would not be used for training? How does this method affect the accuracy of the model?

Comment: I guess the major advantage is that through this approach you get a more robust training model. On the other hand you should know the architecture of your model already. Don't you?

Comment: Currently, I don't use patches to train my model. I use augmented images of the same size. I'm not used to the idea of patches that's why my original question was that resizing downscaled to the original size is recommended or should I just leave it as it after downscaling?